# Кнопки в таблице javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Есть проект asp.net web api. В котором есть apicontroller.

```
    // GET api/values
    public IQueryable<Contact> Get()
    {                      
        return repository.Contacts;
    }

    // GET api/values/5
    public Contact Get(string id)
    {
        var tempcontact = repository.SearchContact(id);            
        return tempcontact;
    }

    // POST api/values
    [HttpPost]
    public void Post(Contact value)
    {            
        if (ModelState.IsValid && value!=null)
        {
            repository.SaveContact(value);
        }
    }

    // PUT api/values/5
    [HttpPut]
    public void Put(int id, Contact value)
    {            
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            repository.SaveContact(value);
        }   
    }

    // DELETE api/values/5
    [HttpDelete]
    public void Delete(int id)
    {            
        repository.DeleteContact(id);
    }
}
```

Так же есть View и функции javascript которые обращаются к api.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'http://localhost:55285/api/values/',
                    type: 'Get',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (dataContacts) {
                        WriteResponse(dataContacts);
                    },
                    error: function (x, y, z) {
                        alert(x + '\n' + y + '\n' + z);
                    }
                });
        });
```

Так же функция рисующая таблицу в которой есть кнопки. И эти кнопки не работают. На эти кнопки есть тоже функции js которые вызываются при нажатие. Если создать кнопки не js, а во view то все работает. В базе данных порядка 500+ записей и к каждой записи нужна кнопка. В какую сторону идти и что искать? Гугл не может помочь так как не знаю что искать.

```
function WriteResponse(contacts) {
            var strResult = "";
            var iio = 0;
            $.each(contacts, function (index, contact) {               
            strResult += "<div class=\"row\">";
            strResult += "<input class=\"form-control\" value=\"" + contact.ContactID + "\"/><input class=\"form-control\" value=\"" + contact.first_name + "\"/>
            strResult += "<div class=\"col-md-1\"><button id=\"DeleteBtn\" data-action=\"Delete\" class=\"btn btn-default\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk\"></span></button><button id=\"SaveBtn\" data-action=\"Save\" class=\"btn btn-default\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-remove\"></span></button></div></div>";

            });
            $("#divResult").html(strResult);            
        }
```

Один из обработчиков.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            jQuery.support.cors = true;
            $("#SaveBtn").click(function () {
                var contact = {                        
                    first_name: $("#first_name").val(),

                };
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'http://localhost:55285/api/values/',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: JSON.stringify(contact),
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    success: function (data) { },
                    error: function (x, y, z) {
                        alert(x + '\n' + y + '\n' + z);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: пробовали отладчик в браузере смотреть? может в консоль что-то падает с ошибкой, а ещё в представленном JS обработки клика на кнопку нет, может в этом проблема?

Comment: Ошибок нет. Переставленный js только подгружает и делать таблицу когда загружается страница. Обработчики на кнопку стоят другие. Добавил один обработчик, схематичный он. Так же есть вопрос как поменить id каждый элемент first_name.

Comment: что-то странно у вас в AJAX происходит, как вы определяете удаляете вы элементы или редактируете?

Comment: не понял вопрос. Сервер же принемает post запрос в котором public void Post(Contact value). Помимо этого в планах расширить модель и добавить другие данные, а не только first_name.

Comment: да я поправил вопрос, мне кажется тут вообще не нужен AJAX, вам нужно организовать ваш код так, чтобы при обращении: `http://localhost:55285/api/values/delete/5` происходило удаление, а при обращение `http://localhost:55285/api/values/get/5` перекидывало на страницу редактирования.

Comment: Это я понимаю. Возможно ли сделать именно на ajax? Что бы перезагружать только часть view. Просто созданные кнопки в WriteResponse. Не прорываются к обработчику. Обработчик их не видет.

Comment: чтобы вновь созданные кнопки работали нужно написать так: `$('body').on('click', '#SaveBtn', function () {  // код });`. И ещё у вас очень большая проблема, на странице не должно быть одинаковых `ID`, нужно чтобы это были классы

Comment: это куда писать? изменить обработчик?

Comment: с id я понял уже решаю проблему

Comment: да, там где вы обрабатываете клик на кнопки, должно вызываться через `on('click')`

Comment: Спасибо это то что надо было. Заработало.